# stbuild not found

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to build native application for ios using sencha touch but every time I use packaging command it gives me error that stbuild in not an external and internal command.
I searched a lot on this problem but did not get any solution.

Answer (score 3):

I had a same problem.
But it worked when I run SenchaSDKTools/stbuild.pkg.

like below:

> /Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/stbuild.pkg

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed "[`Sencha SDK Tools`](http://www.sencha.com/products/sdk-tools/)"? If not, then you should install it.

You can also use the `sencha` command for native packaging of the application.

Like,

```
sencha package generate <configTemplate.json>
```

- [Sencha Touch 2 Native Packaging for Android](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/native_android)
- [Sencha Touch 2 Native Packaging for iOS](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/native_packaging)

Answer (score 0):

If you ***have*** already installed the Sencha SDK Tools, the executable file stbuild.exe file will be installed into the windows system root folder (e.g. C:\Windows) while a subdirectory named stbuild will be installed in the same folder.  Check to see if it is there.  If it is not, it can be downloaded separately from http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8793605/stbuild.msi.

This can happen if the SenchaTouch installer goes awry. In my case the installer won't run on my Windows 7 system, so I duplicated it's effects manually from a Windows XP install.

**NOTE**: From my research it appears that from the version 2.1 tools onwards, the stbuild will be installed to the sencha tools location and no longer into the windows system directory (which is as it always should have been! - I don't know what they were thinking).